# Shopping UX where pressing the "price" turns into "buy-confirm" then "checkout"

Tags: android, ios, shopping-cart

I'm trying to optimize the in app purchase for my users who only want to buy, and checkout as quickly as possible.

**Current situation**

My store offers other things for sale, but when a user only wants on thing, I'd like to streamline this flow:

1. User finds item
2. User clicks on item to item details
3. User clicks on shopping cart (usually in the hard-to-reach upper right hand corner)
4. User clicks checkout.
5. User uses Apple pay to purchase

This requires more finger-acrobatics than I want

**Proposed situation**

How should I design a row of "something to buy" where I streamline this?

Is it a good idea to compact those actions into a single row? Where....

- Each product (row) has a price, and the price can be clicked on.
- Clicking outside of the price hotspot will show product details
- Clicking on the price will replace the price with "buy now"; clicking again will offer to "check out"

Perhaps I could animate this with the entire row shifting left to expose the convertible "buy now" and "check out" button.

**Additional thoughts**

What are your thoughts on this UI/UX implementation?

Is there a better way to go about it?

Does this work for all mobile users?

Comment: This idea has potential but also some possible problems.  I think it will come down to the actual design...could you provide some mockups in your question?

Comment: Possible problems I see: how does the user know that the price is clickable?  Is there still a route to add multiple items to the cart, and how are they differentiated?

Comment: You can use single button with label like "Buy for $25", which is transformed to "Check out".

Comment: I have some questions about this: What happens if I want to buy more than one item? What happens if I want to buy multiples of a single item? What happens if I want to modify the contents of my cart before I buy?

Comment: User test this and see if people are familiar with certain things. Right now, this seems like a stretch because you're breaking the fold from what people are accustomed to. Are you thinking of doing a buy now/ add to cart button on the search results page? If so, I wouldn't recommend it because people need more details before buying. Unless, of course, that this page is for re-purchasing previously purchased products.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the mobile version of amazons 1click ordering,  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Click)

In your case would be interesting if it were a 1 swipe checkout. this will be only for returning customers as their previous purchase info like payment and delivery will be used